# Zoom multiple levels with single click - Google Maps

Tags: php, javascript, maps

This is what I'm trying to accomplish - when the user clicks (single click) anywhere on a map, it zooms in to a pre-specified zoom level. For instance, regardless of the current zoom level, clicking somewhere zooms into that area with zoom level 11.

If necessary, I'm fine with reloading the page to accomplish this but then I would need to save the latitude/longitude somehow (PHP GET variables?) in order to know where to center the map, right?

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo tutorial:

1. Register a `click` event for your map.
2. Do `map.setCenter()` on your lat/lng click location.
3. Do `map.setZoom(11)` on click.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Where `map` is your current Google Map 
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                    map.setCenter();
                    map.setZoom(11);                       
 });
```